# how to bind the dropdown list

Tags: linq, syntax

Please help I am getting the following error when I am binding the drop down list in the form 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

I have written the query in Linq language

return (IList )(from p in db.tbl_PRODUCT_CATEGORY
                        select new
                        {
                            catname = p.category_name,
                            catid = p.category_id,
                        });

I don't know whether it is correct

Please give me the correct format of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query should look more like this:

```
return (IList)(from p in db.tbl_PRODUCT_CATEGORY select new { catname = p.category_name, catid = p.category_id, }).ToList();
```